# Angular ui sref not working with touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have a link with ui-sref attribute and also a jQuery touch event, but the problem is that when i click on this element the jQuery handler is running but the ui-sref not.

Jquery:

```
$('#fa-bar, #mobile-nav li').on('touchstart', function( e ) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('toggle-mobile-nav');
      $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('prevent-scroll');
 });
```

Html:

```
 <li ui-sref="state" ui-sref-active="nav-active"><a>Link</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) and this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation):

> However, stopEvent also calls an event object method, event.stopPropagation, which keeps the event from bubbling any further up into the DOM. Note that the table itself has an onclick event handler that ought to display a message when the table is clicked. But the stopEvent method has stopped propagation, and so after the data in the table is updated, the event phase is effectively ended, and an alert box is displayed to confirm this.

This is pure javascript and also applies for AngularJS. Your call to `e.stopPropagation()` prevents ui-router from getting the event. This is sometimes handy if you want to add an URL to something (so you can still use open-in-new-tab feature of your browser), but want a different behavior on *normal* clicks.

Comment: So how can i use both methods?

Comment: You should be fine if you remove the line `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: But it will not bubble down to the body, cause i have there handler too?

Comment: I think ui-router will stop the propagation after handling it (this is how it prevents the normal follow link behavior of the browser).

Comment: It is still not working, the jquery runs but the ui sref does not redirect to the state.

Comment: I just realized that you attached the `ui-sref` to the `li` element. It should be attached to `a` elements instead.

Comment: This has effect where the ui sref is?

Answer (score 0):

Use latest or atleast 0.3.2 for ui-router

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```